# How to select all the tables from SQL Server is connected remotely via the internet using C #?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a question like this!

How to select all the tables from SQL Server is connected remotely via the internet from another machine using C #?

If possible, select all the fields in a database table any of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//connectionstring will have all your SqlServer name user id and password

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```